# Pair of blocks in each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

As in the standart cycle:

```
- @goods.each do |good|
  ???
```

...to organize this (HAML):

```
.columns-wrapper
  .column First good
  .column Second good
  .column Third good

.columns-wrapper
  .column Fourth good
  .column Fifth good
  .column Sixth good
```

Comment: The question? "What is a standart cycle?"

Comment: The code speaks for itself, English obviously isn't his first language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example, it doesn't look like you want multiple blocks — you want to turn one dataset into several. I think what you want is `each_slice(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'active_record'

@goods.in_groups_of 3, false do |goods|
  goods.each do |good|
    ...
  end
end
```